# Situation with google maps premium features / Streetview images large

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Does anyone have an idea what is the situation with extended features which were possible under google maps premium, now that the plan has being abandoned with Googles recent switch to a unified pay-as-you-go pricing model ?

The specific reason I ask is that I am trying to find out if it is still possible request larger streetview images ?

Under the previous plans maximum resolution for standard users was 640 x 640, but premium users could request up to 2048 x 2048. This required the addition of a client id to the api call. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key#premium-auth)

> Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers who are correctly signing
>   their URLs can request images up to 2048 x 2048 pixels.
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/usage-and-billing

This summer Google merged the Standard and Premium plans to form one pay-as-you-go pricing plan.

I have tried reaching out to their support but no response.

Thanks in advance.

keith

Comment: Did you create support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support link? Typically Google answers support cases. I believe, in order to use big images your project should be configured by Google, so you have to contact them anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming.

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic for this site. You better wait for an official answer from their support team (can take a while but should happen within a few days/weeks) or test it by yourself. It shouldn't be too hard to see what you get from the API.

Comment: Hi All, No problem if ye want o close this .k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue open here
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110570733

> Marked as fixed.
>   We now have an update on this issue: access to 2048x2048 Static Maps will be granted on a case by case basis.
>   Please create a support case to open a personalized communication channel
>   https://support.google.com/googleapi/contact/maps_api_tech_support